# Player & Enemy 2D auto-rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d

I have a player at the bottom of the screen, and an enemy at the top of the screen. I want them both to continuously rotate towards each other. Here is my code for both:

```
void Update () 
    {
        Vector3 diff = target.position - transform.position; 
        diff.Normalize();

        float zRotation = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Vector3 lookDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, zRotation - 90);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(lookDirection);   
    }
```

Given this state, the player behaves as expected, but the enemy always rotates away from the player, meaning that he looks up instead of down at where the player is.

If I switched the `diff` vector like this:

```
Vector3 diff = transform.position - target.position;
```

Then it's the player that looks away from the enemy. 
 Both sprites have 0 values for rotation and scale in the editor.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwsJS.jpg

Could it be that the "up" for the Enemy is the "down" for the player. Meaning one of your sprites is drawn upside down?

You can try the following, but it yields the same result:

```
var dir = target.position - transform.position;
var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

If you're going to use the same method of calculating the rotation, you need to assure that your sprites have the same world-relative native rotation, or fix that.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2D. I only want to rotate on the Z-Axis.

Comment: So alter the values of the target to 0 on x and y

Comment: Have you tried using the function in 2D? Can you make it work using my code above?

Comment: I have not, I'll have a look within two hours. What is your prefered setup? Same script on 2 objects, making them look at each other?

Comment: Exactly, with the default 2D view .

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I just used "Flip Y" on the enemy and it worked, I don't know if it's upside down or not because it's just a rectangle shape, but for some reason it worked!!!
Thanks anyway.